# How do Trinitarians interpret Acts 2:22 in terms of St. Peter's beliefs?

Tags: exegesis, trinity, acts, peter, unitarianism

Acts 2:22 quotes St. Peter saying

> "Men of Israel, listen to this message: Jesus of Nazareth was **a man**
> certified **by God** to you by miracles, wonders, and signs, which **God did**
> among you **through Him**, as you yourselves know."

The distinction between God, on the one hand, and Jesus, a man, seems fairly clear here, and comports with Unitarian views of God. This distinction is also clear throughout the rest of St. Peter's speech (for ex., 2:36 "Therefore let all Israel know with certainty that God has made this Jesus, whom you crucified, both Lord and Christ!").

How do Trinitarians understand Peter's beliefs at Acts 2:22? Do Trinitarians think Peter is a Unitarian in beliefs, or do Trinitarians attribute proto-Trinitarian beliefs to Peter that aren't clearly expressed here? If so, how would they paraphrase Acts 2:22 so as to make clear what Peter is saying about Jesus and God?

Comment: This question focuses on a single text attempting a generalisation. No doctrine can be established by examining a single text. The Council of Nicea was very clear on the matter of the duality of the nature of Christ (Deity and humanity meeting in a single person without mixing or merging). I fail to see any fruitful purpose in repeatedly questioning what has already been made abundantly clear in established documentation. Studying the relevant documents of the Council of Nicea fully explains all that is required, here.

Comment: Notice that the text does not say " Jesus of Nazareth was a man, *and nothing but a man*, certified by God...."  Jesus was indeed a man and Peter correctly expresses it without definition or limitation.

Comment: @NigelJ No, I am not suggesting a general doctrine can be derived from one statement in, in this case, Acts. If studying the 'relevant documents' 'explains all' then why not post such an answer?

Comment: @MikeBorden If Jesus is God, why would he have to be certified by God? Did Peter hold to proto-Trinitarian views? If so, how is the use of words explained here?

Comment: This *"If so, how would they paraphrase Acts 2:22 so as to make clear what Peter is saying about Jesus and God?"* isn't really a valid request, as it is asking us to basically rewrite Scripture. Plenty of other Scriptures assert the Trinity. God did not choose to do so here; why ask us to insert what God chose not to, to make a case that God Himself made through the evidence of the rest of Scripture? This looks like cherry-picked anti-Trinitarian polemics disguised as a question.

Comment: @bob Your comment is sounding like a polemic disguised as a comment! I think you need to do some Trinitarianism push-ups and get that flabby theological stomach in shape!

Comment: @OneGodtheFather The mighty works, wonders, etc. demonstrate that Jesus was from God.  It's not a certification like a CPA.  It's a demonstration.  Jesus said, "If you don't believe my words, at least believe based on the works that I do."  Believe what?  That he came out of/out from God (a separation of a part from the whole.  Seriously, look it up in Acts 2:22)  That He and the Father are one.  That He called God his own Father, making himself equal with God.  That He is the Christ.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather The preposition απο (apo) can often be translated with "from" or "out of" but marks more than simply origin, as would the preposition εκ (ek). Instead, απο (apo) emphasizes **the former relationship of elements that had always existed independently but joined within a realm of origin, and the present separation from both that realm and the other element(s)**.  This is what is meant by Jesus came from God.

Comment: @MikeBorden Sounds like that might be the basis of an important answer.

Comment: @OneGodTheFather My comment was refuting the validity of the question, but it was not a personal attack. And while we all need to grow in our theology daily, the Scripture does indeed support Trinitarian theology. Without it for e.g. you would have during the triumphal entry a mere man accepting worship from his disciples, which if He were not God would be blasphemy. But since He is God, then his actions were not sinful, for God is worthy of all praise. And there is Jesus asking His disciples why they asked Him to show them the Father...

Comment: ...here it is: “3And if I go and prepare a place for you, I will come again and will take you to myself, that where I am you may be also. 4And you know the way to where I am going.”c 5Thomas said to him, “Lord, we do not know where you are going. How can we know the way?” 6Jesus said to him, “I am the way, and the truth, and the life. No one comes to the Father except through me. 7If you had known me, you would have known my Father also.d From now on you do know him and have seen him.” (John 14:3-7) and...

Comment: ... John 14:8-11: “ 8Philip said to him, “Lord, show us the Father, and it is enough for us.” 9Jesus said to him, “Have I been with you so long, and you still do not know me, Philip? Whoever has seen me has seen the Father. How can you say, ‘Show us the Father’? 10Do you not believe that I am in the Father and the Father is in me? The words that I say to you I do not speak on my own authority, but the Father who dwells in me does his works. 11Believe me that I am in the Father and the Father is in me, or else believe on account of the works themselves.”

Comment: There are many more Scriptures like this both Old and New Testament. But it is important to take the Bible as a whole. We can always cherry-pick to make things appear to say whatever we want. But if we throw away God’s Word, we err greatly, and if we throw away a key part of the gospel (who Jesus is, that He is God’s Son, which his fellow Israelites recognized was a divinity claim), we err in a way that blocks our way to the Father

Comment: If fact in Matthew 16:16 Peter himself acknowledges Jesus’ divinity by affirming that He is God’s Son (which the Israelites make clear that calling someone God’s Son is calling that person God, when they attempt to stone Jesus for claiming rightly to be God’s Son).

Comment: @Bob Was Nathanael up and calling Jesus God in John 1? That's ... quite a claim! Son of God does not equal God the Son. Cf. Ps. 2, where the idea of the Son of God, the King of Israel, and the Messiah (= anointed one) are all used as co-referents. Re John 14, if co-inherence means Jesus and the Father are both God, then it seems to follow that the Apostles and Jesus are all God, as Jesus says they will be in Him and Him in them, and indeed them in the Father! This is what I'm saying about Trinitarian muscles - you perhaps don't get a workout often because you are surrounded by Trinitarians.

Comment: Re Nathanael I don't know for sure to be honest because I don't think we have much more evidence of Nathanael's beliefs in the Scripture or whether he fully understood at that time, though I disagree that it is a bold claim. But your use of Ps. 2 is problematic, because Hebrews 1 quotes Ps. 2 about the Son of God, also affirming the Son of God to be God (e.g. see Hebrews 1:8-9). But as another comment has warned, these comments are not the place for this debate. If we continue this, let's do it in chat (not sure how to create a chat room).

Answer (score 5):

And how exactly would you rather have him start ?

> <sup>(Acts 2:22)</sup> ***Men of Israel,** listen to this message: **Jesus of Nazareth was a GOD** certified by God to you by miracles, wonders, and signs, which God did among you through Him, as you yourselves know.*

Don't you recall what happened the last time around ?

> <sup>(John 5:17-18)</sup> Jesus answered them: ***My Father works hitherto, and I work.*** Therefore **the Jews sought the more to kill him,** because he not only had broken the Sabbath, but said also that God was his Father, **making himself equal with God.**

> <sup>(John 10:30-33)</sup> ***I and my Father are one.*** Then **the Jews took up stones again to stone him.** Jesus answered them: *Many good works have I showed you from my Father; for which of those works do **ye stone me ?*** The Jews answered him, saying: *For a good work **we stone thee** not; but for blasphemy; and because that **thou, being a man, make thyself God.***

If even the simple sentences *My Father works hitherto, and I work,* or *I and my Father are one* could determine the Jewish audience to respond in such drastic ways, perhaps easing them into it would have been better than the alternative ? Just saying; after all, we all know how Christ's story ended, don't we ?

> <sup>(Acts 2:23)</sup> This man was handed over to you by God’s deliberate plan and foreknowledge; and you, with the help of wicked men, **put him to death by nailing him to the cross.**

As a general rule in life, when addressing any audience, it is usually recommended to start off with statements with whom most, if not all, are already in agreement.

Comment: Speaking of general rules in life, the fourth century **Trinitarian** bishop [John Chrysostom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Chrysostom) wrote [commentaries on almost every book of the New Covenant](http://www.ccel.org/fathers); his interpretation of this particular passage can be found [here](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf111/npnf111.vi.vi.html).

Comment: Are you saying St. Peter was misleading his audience (leading them to believe Jesus is *not* God) because he didn't want to be killed?

Comment: @OneGodtheFather: Seeing as his speech is longer than just one verse, no. But, like any math teacher, he did not begin by stating (assuming) what he was meant to show (prove), especially not to a potentially volatile crowd. Notice the carefully paced crescendo from *man* to *lord*.

Comment: Are you saying Peter by saying 'Lord' in 'Lord and Christ' meant to suggest to the crowd that Jesus is God?

Comment: @OneGodtheFather: This is the Trinitarian understanding.

Comment: Is your position that he started off by calling Jesus a man, then called Him Lord, as a way to suggest Jesus is God but not definitively state it, so as to avoid being killed by the crowd he was addressing? So he could maintain some kind of plausible deniability if they picked up stones, say?

Comment: Does Chrysostom in his commentary address this particular point, or say things directly relevant?

Comment: @OneGodtheFather Probably not about maintaining "plausible deniability" but about not starting in a confrontational manner. If you are trying to convince people of something, it makes little sense to start with the thing they are least like to find acceptable. Instead start with saying *true* things that will be less objectionable, and work up to the difficult ones.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather: **(1).** I don't think Peter would have been particularly inclined to renounce Christ *yet again*, since the first time seems to have been particularly traumatizing for him (Matthew 26:75, Mark 14:72, Luke 22:61-62). **(2).** If you can't even be [bothered](http://ro.wikisource.org/wiki/Povestea_unui_om_leneș) to read a simple text for yourself, then I see no point in any further conversation.

Comment: From a rhetorician: Adapting one's message to a particular audience often requires a little diplomacy, which comes from preparing one's message with a given audience in mind. Don

Comment: @Lucian Re 2, it is not clear to me why you can't say what you think is relevant. I have read most of it. What do you think is directly relevant to this question?

Comment: @rhetorician I find this argument quite interesting! Since there is no point at which he reveals Jesus' divinity to his audience, is this going beyond being diplomatic and hiding a relevant truth?

Comment: @DJClayworth "If you are trying to convince people of something, it makes little sense to start with the thing they are least like to find acceptable." He definitely didn't start off with that claim. Are you saying he *does* make that claim somewhere else in his speech to the crowd?

Comment: No. Pete wasn't hiding a truth; he was simply holding an idea in abeyance, perhaps until his audience could digest such a "controversial" doctrine. Look no further than 2 Peter 1:1, to learn of Peter's estimation of the personhood of Jesus: "Simon Peter, a servant and apostle of Jesus Christ, To those who through the righteousness of our God and Savior Jesus Christ have received a faith as precious as ours . . .."

Comment: @OneGodtheFather Not in the parts recorded in Acts 2. rhetorician has hit the nail on the head.

Comment: @rhetorician Are you saying this argument re an interpretation of Acts 2:22 depends on 1. holding Peter is the author of 2 Peter, and 2. holding that 2 Peter 1:1 is claiming Jesus is God, similar to Titus 2:13? Or is there other evidence you think is also relevant re Peter's beliefs?

Comment: We have another evidence of Peter’s beliefs: he affirms in one of his epistles that Paul’s epistles are Scripture, and Paul frequently and strongly affirms that Jesus is God. So we have indirect as well as direct evidence of Peter’s beliefs. Besides, what he and others wrote as a scripture wasn’t a matter of their beliefs (though they believed it to be sure)—it was the words of God by the Holy Spirit, with a unified single message. Peter preached the same gospel as Paul, the same as James, the same as John...

Comment: @Bob Workout time! "Paul frequently and strongly affirms that Jesus is God" Frequently and strongly - where? Please don't reference a bunch of places where you think Paul 'implies'.

Comment: @OneGodTheFather Are you asking me to provide references, or something else? If references, it will take some time as there are many. Though it might be better to instead refer you and other readers to answers on the many other "defend Trinitarianism" type questions on this site. This type of question gets asked and answered a lot here, and I would just be repeating much of the same long list of verses. The answers don't change.

Comment: I'm always happy to discuss and defend the truth, but I do not think the onus is on Trinitarians to exhaustively defend their position each and every time it is questioned; rather I think the onus is on those attacking it to build a strong, complete defense of their position, free of cherry-picking.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather better take that to chat or another question, you guys are popping up on the mod radar with this conversation

Answer (score 1):

They would interpret it in light of the whole of the Scripture, with many many passages that together show that Jesus is God. They would not paraphrase this verse differently than it is written, because there is no need to do so. God chose it to be as it is, and it is not in conflict with Trinitarianism.