# How do Trinitarians explain that Jesus himself claims He is a man who has heard things from God at John 8:40?

Tags: exegesis, christology, gospel-of-john, acts, hypostatic-union

In Acts 2:22, St. Peter says

> "Fellow Israelites, listen to this! Jesus of Nazareth **was a man**
> who had God's **approval**."

I have asked about this particular line [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/84353/how-do-trinitarians-interpret-acts-222-in-terms-of-st-peters-beliefs).

Similarly, Jesus himself at John 8:40 says

> "But now you are trying to kill Me, **a man** who has told you the truth
> that **I heard from** God."

The main answer to the question linked above about St. Peter's sermon was that it was too much for St. Peter to come right out and call Jesus God, so he discreetly laid that aside (seemingly for all of Acts!), even though that would have been misleading to the Jews assembled there.

Yet, Jesus himself says something very similar at John 8:40. What are the main lines of reasoning by Trinitarians regarding why Jesus would say "I am a man (no mention of also being God) who has heard things from God (suggesting he isn't God)"?

Comment: False dichotomy is an invalid premise.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Where's a false dichotomy in the question?

Comment: the presumption of either God or Man

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Where is that presumption in the question?

Comment: No mention of him also being a God? John 8:48-59 : Jesus said to them, “Truly, truly, I say to you, before Abraham was, I am.”

Comment: @stackoverblown See my comments on DJClayworth's answer. He doesn't seem to think that's relevant, but I do. ;)

Comment: @bob Who do you think asked that question? ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do Trinitarians interpret Acts 2:22 in terms of St. Peter's beliefs?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/84353/how-do-trinitarians-interpret-acts-222-in-terms-of-st-peters-beliefs)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Who do you think asked that question? ;)

Comment: I didn't write that comment; the auto feature of SE did that. I really, really don't like the feature change on how SE does auto comments that use a person's name; I'd rather put in a comment or not as I am moved to. 

Answer (score 15):

It's a common misapprehension that Trinitarians do not believe the Jesus was a man. However they do believe that. The core of Trinitarian belief is that Jesus is both Man and God.

Also God the Son deliberately and voluntarily made himself dependent on God the Father as part of the incarnation. He chose to be reliant on the Father for his power, his knowledge. So Jesus is absolutely correct to say that he is a man, and to say that he has heard things from God.

While you could theoretically argue that Jesus might have said "I am a man and God", such a statement would not be relevant to the point he was trying to make and would almost certainly have distracted from it.

Comment: +1 Do you hold that Jesus *was* claiming to be God at 8:58, soon after 8:40?

Comment: What's the relevance of that question?

Comment: You're saying it wasn't relevant at 8:40. I'm asking whether you think it was relevant at 8:58.

Comment: Probably a separate question.

Comment: I'm not saying it isn't relevant, I'm asking what the relevance is in your mind?

Comment: @DJClayworth If the Jews were trying to kill Jesus, isn't it even more relevant that He's God than that He 'heard things from' God? Abraham listened to God, didn't try to kill God!

Comment: @DJClayworth This answer turns on the idea that it just wasn't that relevant at 8:40, so why mention it? *So* not relevant that Jesus gives a misleading answer (the inference to ancient Jews would be that he is **only** a man, given the statements He makes at 8:40). Yet do you simultaneously think He then up and tells them He *is* God at 8:58, almost out of the blue? I think it's relevant because those two beliefs seems to me in tension.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather, I think I would interpret v40 as "soft selling". That is, Jesus is making a true, but more palatable statement to try to convince His audience (IOW, exactly DJ's point about distracting from the point He's trying to make). As the Jews continue to push back (v57), He "plays His trump card" (v58).

Comment: @Matthew That's a logical take. I still find it incongruous. Jesus didn't need to up and state that at 58. And where does Jesus 'soft sell' in other topics? He's extremely bold, and often insults the Jewish elites to their faces in the strongest language. Similarly with Peter. He is jailed repeatedly, beaten, tells the Jewish elite they killed the Christ, and is repeatedly characterized as speaking boldly in Acts. But we're supposed to believe he wanted to be discreet about the extremely important claim that Jesus is God Almighty in the ontological sense? Seems implausible to me.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather, *Jesus* was more gradual in His ministry (which, in a sense, started with John the Baptist). Note John 6 in particular.

Comment: @Matthew You call what Jesus did in John 6 *gradual*? ;) It seems to me extremely straightforward, if not intentionally provocative.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather, in the sense that He apparently wasn't saying such things prior to John 6. Perhaps we can argue over "gradual", but the point is He said "harder" things later in His ministry that He (apparently) didn't say earlier on. This being the case, why should it be so strange that He did the same on a smaller scale in John 8?

Comment: @Matthew I think you're right in a sense, but I take what Jesus is saying at John 6 to be a restatement of the basic thesis of the Gospel of John, which is repeated again and again but which Jesus originally acknowledges at John 1 in response to Nathanael. Jesus is the Christ who gives Living Water (John 4), the Bread of Life (John 6), the Light (John 8), the Gate (John 10), the Resurrection and Life (John 11, 14), the Way (John 14), the Vine (John 15). These are all variations on the basic idea that Jesus is the Christ, the Son of God (John's main point of his Gospel, John 20:31).

Answer (score 5):

The trinitarian understanding hinges, in part, on what is meant by *morphe* in Philippians 2:

> Who, being in the **form** of God, thought it not robbery to be equal with God: But made himself of no reputation, and took upon him the **form** of a servant, and was made in the likeness of men,... - Philippians 2:6-7

One cannot simultaneously say that "in the form of God" **does not** mean he was God but that "in the form of a servant" **does** mean that he was human.  Whatever "in the form" of a servant means so also "in the form" of God must mean.

The only other time this form (pun unavoidable) of *morphe* is used is Mark 16:12 which says:

> After that he appeared in another form unto two of them, as they walked, and went into the country.

One might be led to believe that Jesus changed his outward appearance by this verse alone however, reading the more detailed account of this incident in Luke 24 reveals that it was the eyes (or perception) of the disciples that were restrained from recognizing Jesus:

> And it came to pass, that, while they communed together and reasoned, Jesus himself drew near, and went with them. But their eyes were holden that they should not know him. - Luke 24:15-16

And when they did recognize him, the opening of their eyes is not linked to a change of outward appearance but to a recognizable action or behavior:

> And it came to pass, as he sat at meat with them, he took bread, and blessed it, and brake, and gave to them. And their eyes were opened, and they knew him; and he vanished out of their sight. - Luke 24:30-31

By this we can understand the Philippians passage with more specificity.  It is not the outward appearance of God and of a servant that is in view (and this makes sense because God, being Spirit, has no outward appearance) but, rather, that perception that is linked to behavior.

With this understanding Philippians 2:6-7 might be rendered something like this:  "Even though he had every right to behave and appear as God he abased himself and behaved and appeared as a servant".  And this understanding not only makes sense of John 8:40 and so many other passages where Jesus acts and speaks as a man:

> But now ye seek to kill me, a man that hath told you the truth, which I have heard of God: this did not Abraham. - John 8:40

But it also makes sense of the times where Jesus implores us that, if we won't believe his words, we should at least believe his works:

> Say ye of him, whom the Father hath sanctified, and sent into the world, Thou blasphemest; because I said, I am the Son of God? If I do not the works of my Father, believe me not. But if I do, though ye believe not me, believe the works: that ye may know, and believe, that the Father is in me, and I in him. - John 10:36-38

> Believest thou not that I am in the Father, and the Father in me? the words that I speak unto you I speak not of myself: but the Father that dwelleth in me, he doeth the works. Believe me that I am in the Father, and the Father in me: or else believe me for the very works' sake. - John 14:10-11

These works are the works of his Father.  They are the behaviors of God which are meant to affect our perception so that we may see who he is.

Though he rightly had the behavior/nature (in the *form*) of God, He adopted the behavior/nature (in the *form*) of a servant and was made in the resemblance (likeness) of a man and, being found in the outward appearance (fashion) of a man he humbled himself, as a man should, and became obedient (to God) as a man should.

He acted and spoke as a man so that we could perceive him as such but he also performed the works of God, humbly (as a servant) saying that it was the Father in Him doing the works, and begging us to believe **at the very least** because of the works (*morphe*) of the Father in him.

Why did Jesus so often refer to himself as a man and only vaguely and seldom (according to some) refer to himself as God?  It is not so.  Seeing they see not and hearing they hear not, neither do they understand as a fulfillment of prophesy:

> Therefore speak I to them in parables: because they seeing see not; and hearing they hear not, neither do they understand. And in them is fulfilled the prophecy of Esaias, which saith, By hearing ye shall hear, and shall not understand; and seeing ye shall see, and shall not perceive: For this people's heart is waxed gross, and their ears are dull of hearing, and their eyes they have closed; lest at any time they should see with their eyes, and hear with their ears, and should understand with their heart, and should be converted, and I should heal them. - Matthew 13:13-15

It is not that he did not behave/appear as God (believe because of the works!)... it is that our eyes are holden that we should not know him.  It is no accident nor meaningless that opening blind eyes is so prominent in the gospel accounts and is given as a sign of the Christ's coming.  Oh, that he may mercifully open the eyes of the blind if we will but cry out and ask:

> And they came to Jericho: and as he went out of Jericho with his disciples and a great number of people, blind Bartimaeus, the son of Timaeus, sat by the highway side begging. And when he heard that it was Jesus of Nazareth, he began to cry out, and say, Jesus, thou Son of David, have mercy on me. And many charged him that he should hold his peace: but he cried the more a great deal, Thou Son of David, have mercy on me. And Jesus stood still, and commanded him to be called. And they call the blind man, saying unto him, Be of good comfort, rise; he calleth thee. And he, casting away his garment, rose, and came to Jesus. And Jesus answered and said unto him, What wilt thou that I should do unto thee? The blind man said unto him, Lord, that I might receive my sight. And Jesus said unto him, Go thy way; thy faith hath made thee whole. And immediately he received his sight, and followed Jesus in the way. - Mark 10:46-52

Comment: Except for the Trinitarian focus of this particular interpretation, morphe is never referred to apart from an outward appearance. Not some kind of making very God. For eg. Luke 24 and Mark 16 refer to appearance only. https://www.revisedenglishversion.com/Philippians/chapter2/6

Comment: The word in this form only appears in Phil 2 and Mark 16 - 3 times total.  From Thayer:  *the form by which a person or thing strikes the vision*.   I know you wouldn't say he **only** had the outward appearance of a man.   If he strikes your vision as a man he should also strike your vision as God.

Comment: I don't follow this argument.  He originally *was* in the form of God and in fact *was* God. Then later, he gave up his godhood, and *became* temporarily human form and in fact *was* human. Finally, he *regained* his godhood, and *became* permanently in the form of God and in fact *is* God. (I'm not sure whether I'm agreeing or disagreeing with your answer.)

Comment: c'mon @Ray. It must be frustrating for you to see so many things clearly yet not be able to work through things like why Jesus has a God - still does! You're adding your own interpretation and meaning to this passage - it doesn't say anything about Jesus being God - here or anywhere - and for the love of God, how does he stop being GOD and DIE!?

Comment: @MikeBorden God is invisible. What they saw - as 1John also describes - is what God is like, what God does, how God treats people etc. A *representation* of God's manner and nature - NOT substance. You cannot read in *substance* exegetically, So you are then placing the Church Fathers/Creeds over bible which it seems, is the generally accepted practice. Jesus also had the *representation* of a servant's manner and nature. He is STILL the son of God - being a *servant* with *that* status is beyond our apprehension. *Dying on the cross* helps a lot to grasp *what* he did and *how* he did it.

Comment: @RayButterworth I think you are agreeing :-)

Comment: @steveowen If you want to say he had a *representation of God's manner and nature* but *was **not** actually God* then you must say that he had the *representation of a servant's manner and nature* but *was **not** actually a servant*. If you want to say he was actually a servant then you must say that he was actually God. It is the exact same form of the exact same word!

Comment: You can imagine it that way if you like - but you are also imagining him being God in the first instance to support such a theory with all the texts manipulated to make him what he is not - Creator Heb 1:2 for eg, 'ages'. Jesus IS the image of God, having the form of God, being the servant of God, the exalted and heir of God, the anointed of God, the one given authority and eternal life by God. None of that makes any sense if he is God all along. The farcical stuff about him (somehow) stopping being God so he could die, but apparently *needing* to be God to die for all is quite bizarre.

Comment: @steveowen So he was in the **form** of a servant and he **was** a servant but he was in the **form** of God and **was not** God and I'm imagining things?   This word has to do with how one's perception is struck by an object and not how the object appears.  The only other time it appears (Mark 16) we can see this clearly because Luke 24 gives more information.  Jesus did not change his appearance, he arrested their vision (v. 16) until he opened their eyes to see (v. 31).  Jesus is not a shapeshifter.  Those with opened eyes see him as he is ... God and man.

Comment: :) *shapeshifter* - that's exactly what you guys make him!!! God for some things and not for others, oh dear. Putting off God, taking on man, it goes on and on and all fabricated. Anyway, you know all that and it will make sense for you all one day soon - promise! *He committed no sin, and no deceit was found in his mouth*, back to the OP verse, you are putting deceit in his mouth. A man is not a man if he is also God - the man who *has* a God! Jesus says he is a man - if you make him God too, you make him a deceiver and a liar. *I am the way and the truth* - not according to you apparently.

Comment: If you apply your formula to 'form' then you have to apply it to 'image' also. The basic intellect says the image IS NOT the same as that imaged. So in that simple manner, Jesus is not God because he is but the image, the likeness. *...but was not actually a servant* Why is he not a servant? If he has the form of a servant he does the things a servant does if he has the form of God he does, says the things God does. What's the problem?

Comment: @steveowen You've now shifted the definition of *morphe* into behavior rather than perception of appearance.  Luke 24 says something different.  It is that their eyes were "holden", not that he altered his behavior.

Comment: @steveowen Do you have a single passage in mind where Jesus is called both the image of God and the image of man, as is done with "form", so that I can treat "image" the same way, as you suggest?

Comment: *Do you have a single passage in mind where Jesus…* calls himself God? Therefore, while *form* has its interpretive options, going the Jesus is God route is only supported by speculation. Your answer is a distraction avoiding the simplicity of the main Q.

Comment: @steveowen Seriously, you've called me to treat "image" the same as "form" where Scripture does not use it the same and I have provided a distraction?  The simple answer to the simple question is that Jesus was a man who heard things from God.  No Trinitarian struggles with this.  The veiled, unasked, (and therefore not simple)  part of the question is the assumption that Jesus was only a man and it asks after the main lines of reasoning that Jesus, if he was God, would say he was a man.  For this I have attempted to provide an answer with no pushback from OP.

Comment: The issue remains at the very core of this - you make form (outward appearance) = *substance* without a shred of evidence.  If this is *the* *Trinitarian hinge*, it's lacking any credibility. You haven't addressed John 8:40 at all - is that how hermeneutics works? Changing the subject is a ploy seen often around here.

Comment: @steveowen No.  I am suggesting that *form* as it is used in these three places (only) has to do with perception rather than actual outward appearance and I have given Mark 16 as a clear example:  Jesus did not change his *outward appearance* but they were kept from recognizing him (as per Luke's more detailed account).   I will add something to my answer regarding 8:40 directly.

Answer (score -1):

Trinitarians believe that Jesus is God *and* man since the time when Jesus stopped being only immortal and took on flesh. Yet he remained God because God needed to appear to die for the sins of the world.

John 8:40 expresses a moment in time when Jesus is speaking from his flesh - this should not be confused with him being still God at this time because he is in the flesh and this is how he presents himself while on earth. Simultaneously immortal and mortal, knowing and not knowing, supremely powerful but powerless, fully independent but totally dependent. Only his flesh is revealed while his God-ness is hidden (except from Thomas).

Jesus doesn’t ever call himself God or allude to it as he doesn’t want people to be distracted from his ministry in the flesh.

It's not being deceitful or disingenuous to say he is a man when he is really God the whole time. Some say that if Jesus is really God, then this verse makes Jesus a liar - saying he is a man when he is really God. God has light and darkness in His purview (Isaiah 45:7) and can *bend the truth* to suit His divine purposes.

Peter and the other Apostles don't make a big deal about him being God because they didn’t want to make Jesus complicated while pretending to be just a man the whole time.

Jesus depends on God for all his needs, even though he is always God, as he must show absolute dependency - he could do nothing of himself (so he kept *saying* anyway) as an example for those watching.

The important thing to remember is; the bible can be confusing. The Creeds provided by the Church Fathers must be honoured first to ensure things are understood correctly. Only then may the bible be in general agreement with the Creedal principles - anything that seems contradictory is set aside as there are some mysteries that are not yet understood.

Comment: Trinitarians don't hold Jesus "Stopped being immortal"

Comment: @SupportiveDante Do you think Jesus didn't really die?

Comment: Trinitarians both believe that Christ didn't stop being immortal AND that he did really die. Christ as God is immortal and didn't die; Christ as man died and rose.

Comment: @eques Right, so he did stop being immortal in the sense that He took on a human nature, and then died. So mortality-immortality basically becomes a two-fold question with Jesus, because He has two natures. In the most general sense, it is true that He died **and** it is true that He was incapable of death, because 'death' is for him relative to each nature.

Comment: Immortality can also be understood such that if He were mortal, his death would have not conquered death

Comment: @steveowen I'm not sure if you wrote this as satire, but it's actually a pretty good, all-encompassing answer for these sorts of questions. Maybe add 'only' before immortal in the answer, and rework "None of the Apostles refer to him as God either because they didn’t want to make Jesus seem foolish by pretending to be just a man the whole time." which seems a bit of an overstatement? Arguably, some of the Apostles do refer to him as 'theos', and the psychologizing about their motivations doesn't seem supported by the evidence. ?

Comment: @OneGodtheFather no, didn't stop. To say he "stopped" would conflict with what the hypostatic union means in Trinitarian theology. He didn't cease being God in anyway; he only took on a new nature

Comment: steveowen Jesus always existed as God. Philippians 2:6. At His trial Jesus was accused of blasphemy, what was the blasphemy? Matthew 26:57-66. His disciples clearly identified Jesus as God. John 20:28, 2 Peter 1:1, Revelation 1:8, Romans 9:5, and Titus 2:13. There are others. So do you really think that these verses are not a big deal? Moreover, even if Jesus Christ did not say the words, "I am God" would you believe Him? Tell me, what is confusing about the verses quoted? Thomas said, John 20:28, "The Lord of me and the God of me." This is not from a creed nor is it some sort of mystery.

Comment: "except from Thomas"... I don't think Thomas is the only exception. Say, rather, Christ's God-ness is revealed only in glimpses (the Transfiguration, for example), and more often after His resurrection. "Jesus doesn’t ever call himself God", except in John 8:58 (and maybe others, but *definitely* there).

Comment: @eques Whatever you say, boss! But in taking on a new nature, he opened that nature to the possibility of death. And, in fact, died in that nature.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather the key though is that he never ceased to be what He was before the Incarnation. He assumed a new nature but didn't stop being what He was.

Comment: @eques Sure, that's what Trinitarians believe. What is that a key to?

Comment: That one cannot say "stopped" of God

Comment: @eques If someone adds a property of being mortal in one nature, they have ceased to be immortal in general. Rather, they are now only immortal in one of their natures. ?

Comment: @OneGodtheFather Are you using *logic* to dissuade *seemingly* erroneous understanding? This is the core of threeological disputes - Creeds come first and then the bible is massaged to align. Biblically based logic/exegesis has little to do with it. Yes, I know, that is all we have.

Comment: @steveowen Well, here I'm pretty sure it's just a semantic debate. Trinitarians want to say Jesus is immortal, full stop. But what they *mean* is one of his natures is immortal, therefore He's immortal, and He never stopped being immortal. In a sense, this is true. But it's also true that be became mortal, and ceased being immortal in a general sense.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather It's rather that predicating things of Christ or God can run into complications because of the distinction of natures or persons. We don't say Jesus is immortal full stop nor do we say "in a general sense" (because God is not in a genus).